# What new features are available in SQL Server Reporting Services Denali?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

All I've heard is Project Crescent but that's aimed for end users and ad-hoc reporting (and is web based on Silverlight). Are there any new or updated report controls or features planned for report designers using BIDS?

Comment: Read the official microsoft site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much new in Denali for SSRS. I vaguely recall reading that the SSRS team got most of their big enhancements into 2008R2 instead of needing to delay to Denali.

That said, BIDS will be Visual Studio 2010. That's worth a lot on its own.

Also, Word and Excel export will finally support Office OpenXML file formats (.xlsx and .docx) which will remove some limitations from the previous formats. The biggest of these are the row and column counts for Excel exports.

Then Project Crescent that you mentioned: self service Silverlight "Report" story authoring. I'm not sure this will really be part of SSRS proper; I'm not sure where it will fit.

I expect minor enhancements of the existing report objects, but I don't think there will be much new for SSRS in Denali.

Comment: That matches what I've heard. Crescent seems to be the big new thing for this edition- it is the new ad-hoc reporting tool of choice for your MS BI. It is part of SSRS in that it is part of the install, but it is something that is accessed within Sharepoint only. It will run off your cubes (BISM Tabular or Powerpivot only for the CTP I'm using, but apparently old-school SSAS cubes also in future) and it really gives the wow factor.